# Enforce inserting records into multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables `parent` and `child`.  I would like to insert a record in both tables only if the query succeeds for both.  Ideally, integrity would be enforced by the database, however, doing so using the application would be acceptable if necessary.  Potentially, I could do something like the following, however, it seems like there would be a more elegant method to do so.  How should this be accomplished?

```
<?php
//parent must be inserted first as child has a FK constraint to it
$stmt1=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO parent(id,data) VALUES(?,?)');
if($stmt1->execute(array(123,"foo"))) {
    $stmt2=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO child(parent_id,data) VALUES(?,?)');
    if(!$stmt2->execute(array(123,"bar"))) {
        $stmt3=$conn->prepare('DELETE FROM parent WHERE id=?');
        $stmt3->execute(array(123));
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT.  Would something like the following work?

```
<?php

$queries=array(
    array('sql'=>'INSERT INTO parent(id,data) VALUES(?,?)',$data=>array(123,"foo")),
    array('sql'=>'INSERT INTO child(parent_id,data) VALUES(?,?)',$data=>array(123,"bar")),
    //More if necessary array('sql'=>'',$data=>array()),
);

doMultipleQueries($queries);

function doMultipleQueries($queries) {

    try {
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        foreach($queries as $query) {
            $stmt=$conn->prepare($query['sql']);
            $stmt->execute($query['data']);
        }
        $conn->commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $conn->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parent` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `child` (
  `parent_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_child_parent`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `parent` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Still awkward but use a trigger after INSERT

Comment: You can also use a procedure.

Comment: use a transaction as well. if something fails in an later query, you'll want to undo the earlier ones, you're going to end up with crap in the DB.

Comment: I was considering a trigger but wasn't sure, however, wasn't sure how that would be implemented if I had more than two related insert.  Never worked with transactions before and will investigate.

Comment: If you use transactions dont forget `mysqli_multi_query` which I dont know if it accepts placeholder values

Comment: @Mihai  As far as I could tell, `mysqli_multi_query` doesn't work with PDO.

Comment: Maybe PDO has some multi query library? It has http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: @Mihai  Maybe some libraries, but why is it necessary?  I am going to put an initial script together in the next 3 minutes and add it to my original, and hope you could take a quick look

Comment: @Mihai  Okay, 6 minutes, not 3 minutes.  Where would the multi-query part be required?  Does what I show make any sense?  Thank you

Comment: Might work cant tell,just test it.Doesnt work ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should look into database transactions, they will role back all actions if one of them fails

Answer (score 2):

Use a transaction:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Also you can set up your constraint to cascade changes ON DELETES and UPDATES instead of no action.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Never used transactions before, but first look indicates that it is exactly what I want.  I don't see the point of cascading however since the transaction will rollback should any fail, no?

Comment: @user1032531 Yes transaction is all or nothing

Comment: True, but if you delete a parent, you dont want orphan records in the child table. There is more than one way to add update and delete records in a database. Let the database engine do it's job.

Comment: You can't delete a parent with no action, no?

Comment: What's to say you, or someone else goes into the table using phpMySql and deletes a parent record. (Good reason or not) Orphan records can really mess your up. That's why referential integrity is so important. Your interface is only an interface. There's nothing keeping someone from using or setting up a different interface. You also mentioned in your question that you would prefer the database to manage the integrity.

Comment: I agree a DB solution is best, and thank you for suggesting transactions.  But the DB schema will enforce preventing the deletion of a parent record with the `ON DELETE NO ACTION` constraint, no?  Also, I am not saying that `CASCADE` and it seems like most DB guru's promote while many PHP people are less inclined to use.

Answer (score 0):

of course the transaction is the best solution but if do not like to use it, you can use PDO to do multiple queries ,,, [see this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd?lq=1)